# Prevent embedded YouTube videos from autoplaying?

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube, embedded, autoplay

When accessing certain websites that have YouTube videos embedded I have noticed that sometimes when the webpage loads the YouTube video will automatically play and taking a look at the source code it appears this is decided by a modifier to the URL of the embedded video.

My question is whether there is some kind of setting (in any browser or YouTube itself) or perhaps a Chrome extension which allows you to disable autoplaying from any website regardless of whether the URL has been setup to autoplay?

Thus far I haven't been able to find any extension or setting to allow this. Is it possible that some sort of modified certificate for one of the sites that YouTube-embedded videos pull information from could prevent this?

Comment: Would an adBlock browser plugin suite your needs or is it not ads you are asking about?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a way to prevent embedded youtube videos from autoplaying as some sites (especially blogs) have these play automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only for Youtube videos, but for all videos:

In firefox, to stop autoplay, open the `about:config` page and set  `media.autoplay.enabled` to `false`

In Chrome, to stop autoplay, open the `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy` page and choose `Document user activation is required`

After change, relauch your browser.

Comment: #autoplay-policy has apparently been removed, it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a user [**script**](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/25100-stop-youtube-embedded-video-autoplay/code) I wrote that can do this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stop Youtube Embedded Video Autoplay
// @namespace    none
// @version      0.1
// @description  Stop autoplaying YouTube Embedded Videos.
// @author       none
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
'use strict';

var vid = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (var i = 0, l = vid.length; i < l; i++) {
    var vidno = vid[i];
    var reg = new RegExp(/.*youtube.*autoplay=1.*/i);
    if (reg.test(vidno.src)){
        vidno.src=vidno.src.replace("autoplay=1", "autoplay=0");
    }
}


})();
```

You'll just have to create a new UserScript in Greasemonkey,Tampermonkey, etc. It'll run on every page, look for embedded YouTube videos and stop them autoplaying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Chrome extension [Disable autoplay for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-autoplay-for-yout/dinkeiniijmpjehejhedbciaedblhnnk). Or [AutoplayStopper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoplaystopper/ejddcgojdblidajhngkogefpkknnebdh/related?hl=en-US) recommended by @[Taylor D. Edmiston](https://superuser.com/users/44994/taylor-d-edmiston) in [this comment.](https://superuser.com/questions/1149386/prevent-embedded-youtube-videos-from-autoplaying/1149404?noredirect=1#comment2803394_1149404)

On Firefox, you can use [YouTube No Buffer](http://firefox.add0n.com/no-buffer.html).

Comment: Will this prevent autoplay for embedded videos on external sites as well?

Comment: That Chrome extension is a 404 now

Comment: Here's a Chrome extension that seems to (mostly) work now: "AutoplayStopper" - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoplaystopper/ejddcgojdblidajhngkogefpkknnebdh/related?hl=en-US

Comment: @TaylorD.Edmiston Thank you. updated my answer.